# Filtered self cross join in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with a number of rows and need to get a combination of all rows.

For example if I have rows identified by A,B and C, the result would be AB,AC and BC. Essentially it's a cross join where a row joined to itself is omitted and repeated joins of the same pair occur only once.

What's the correct query for this? TIA

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

Comment: What about BA? Do you want it as well as AB?

Comment: No, I want either one but not both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a regular self (inner) join:

```
select t1.col, t2.col
from tablename t1
join tablename t2 on t1.col < t2.col
```

Comment: You beat me by 5 seconds...

Comment: @TheImpaler, I just had a big mug of coffee!